# Blob storage content type

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure and I am moving my on-prem table to Azure blob as csv format.
But in the Azure storage explorer, I am seeing the 'content type' column is showing as 'application/octet-stream' instead of 'csv'? . I am wondering why it is not showing as csv file ? .Can you explain, please ?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

When you upload files in your Azure Storage account usually all files are uploaded with `application/octet-stream` as ContentType. If you just upload .csv files to Azure blob, it doesn't matter. You could change it to `text/csv` that you would like.

**Modify ContentType:**

```
private static CloudBlockBlob TrySetContentType(CloudBlockBlob blob, string contentType)
{
    if (blob.Properties.ContentType.ToLower() != contentType)
    {
        blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
        return blob;
    }

    return null;
}
```

For more details about ContentType property, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobproperties.contenttype?view=azure-dotnet).

In the latest (12.x+) New Azure SDK for .NET, setting content type needs to be done via [`BlobHttpHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobhttpheaders?view=azure-dotnet) object.

```
BlobClient blob = _container.GetBlobClient(fileName);

var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders();
string extension = Path.GetExtension(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
switch (extension.ToLower())
{
    case ".jpg":
    case ".jpeg":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        break;
    case ".png":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/png";
        break;
    case ".gif":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "image/gif";
        break;
    case ".csv":
        blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "text/csv";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

await using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
{
    var uploadedBlob = await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream, blobHttpHeader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Much Pam. But where I should use or insert this code ?

Comment: Hi @GowriShankar, I edit my reply with the full code about modifying ContentType with C#. You could refer to this. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.